# getting image alt text via ACF plugin in WordPress

Tags: plugins, images, post-meta, html, seo

I am using the [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin in my WP 3.3.1 application and I use the `the_field` method in many places across the site. One place in particular I use it is in a slideshow/carousel as below:

`<img alt="" src="<?php the_field('slideshow_image'); ?>" />`

I am trying to pull in the image alt text, which I have stored in `wp_postmeta` under the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` metakey...however, i'm not sure how to access this. Calling `the_field` with "image_alt" does not work and there is limited documentation.

Comment: I have no idea how the question could be classed as "off-topic"? This is a Wordpress-specific issue and I have posted on a Wordpress forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your ACF field to return the image object instead of the URL. You can then use the following code to retrieve the image and alt text:

```
<?php $slideshow_image = get_field('slideshow_image');
// Check for alt text - if there isn't any, use the image title
$alt = ($slideshow_image['alt']?$slideshow_image['alt']:$slideshow_image['title']);
// Return full size image
$url = $slideshow_image['url']; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
```

If you want to return the image at a different size, you can use the sizes array instead of the url:

```
// Return image thumbnail    
$url = $slideshow_image['sizes']['thumbnail'];
```

Documentation here under Customized display: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

EDIT:

This solution works for ACF 3.3.7 and above only. Another method is to return the image/attachment ID, then use `wp_get_attachment_image()` to return the full image HTML.
Documentation here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this does not appear to work for me. When I dump out `$slideshow_image` to the logs I only get the URL of the image. There's no `alt` or `title` keys or indeed it's not an array at all. I'm on an old 3.3.1 version of WP (not sure if that matters or not). What i concerning me is that I have a post ID of `60860`, however when I edit the image in the gallery to set the alt text and then view the entry in `wp_postmeta` it has a different post ID altogether? Is this a bug with my version of WP or a is it my limited understanding of the WordPress inner workings?

Comment: Is your custom field definitely set up as an object? See this screenshot: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/acf-image-field-edit.jpg - the return value needs to be set to image object. I'm not sure if your WordPress version makes a difference here - what version of ACF are you using?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I am using ACF `Version: 3.1.7`. That screenshot is interesting - where can I find that admin on my site?

Comment: Here is my current configuration for the field. http://i.imgur.com/QkFXqJw.png It don't have a "Image object" config option. Was this introduced in a later version of ACF?

Comment: Ah I see, yes image object was added in 3.3.7. In that case, try returning the attachemnt ID instead, then use `wp_get_attachment_image()` to return the full image HTML. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! That worked. Do you want to submit this as an answer and I can accept?

Comment: Glad that helped crmpicco, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Sadly my question has been downvoted for no apparent reason.